# Remote Foreign Key Column in Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've been developing a project with `Kendo UI`. There is a `grid` in my project which consists a couple of **Foreign Key columns**. The workaround which Kendo team has introduced [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn) is to use a static array for `FK`'s.

There are hundreds of records in my grid, if I look forward like Kendo provided in their demo I should retrieve all `FK`s and store them in an array. This workaround has a perf issue! Imagine for a couple of 5 records it should download more than hundred and hundred of `FK`'s.

Is there any workaround to load only foreign keys which are needed? (on-demand load).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vladimir Iliev of Telerik [demonstrates an approach](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-return-a-value-(from-async-call)-to-a-grid's-cell-template-#yQ5XO1K8WkyQUX7H--604A) to use `async` call.

**Define column template:**

```
template: "#=createAsync(data)#"
```

**Define the "createAsync" function:**

```
function createAsync(data) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetCustomData",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: data.OrderID },
        success: function (response) {
            //find the returned element and insert the response
            $("#async_" + data.OrderID).html(response.text);
        }
    });

    //return container with id generated from current model ID field
    return "<div id='async_" + data.OrderID + "'> </div>"
}
```